# How to change my code into taking 2 parameters instead of 4 for Junit Testing?

Tags: java, junit, console

I need to do some Junit testing for my code. However, I have completely coded it so that it takes 4 parameters instead of 2. Can anyone help tweak my code as I have no idea where I'm going wrong ! Basically my code adds and subtracts two times in the console.

class NewTime:

```
public class NewTime {

    public boolean valid24Time(int hh, int mm){
        if(hh<0 || hh>23 || mm < 0 ||mm > 59) //if time is out of range
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public int addTime(int hh1, int mm1, int hh2, int mm2){
        int time1= hh1*60+mm1; //time1 in minutes
        int time2=hh2*60+mm2; //time 2 in minutes
        int time=time2+time1; //add times
        int hh=(time/60)%23; //get hours
        int mm= time%60;    //get minutes
        return hh*100+mm;
    }

    public int subtractTime(int hh1, int mm1, int hh2, int mm2){

        int time1= hh1*60+mm1;//time1 in minutes
        int time2=hh2*60+mm2; //time 2 in minutes
        int time=time2-time1; //subtract times
        int hh=(time/60)%23; //get hours
        int mm= time%60;    //get minutes
        return hh*100+mm;
    }
```

class NewTest:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NewTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewTime time= new NewTime();
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);

        //Testing if time is valid
        System.out.println("Testing if time is valid..");
        System.out.print("Enter time (hhmm): ");
        String input= scanner.nextLine();
        //get hh and mm from input
        int  hh=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));    
        int  mm=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));
        //check if time is valid
        if(time.valid24Time(hh, mm))
            System.out.println(input+" is valid.");
        else
            System.out.println(input+" is invalid.");


        //testing addition of two times
        System.out.println("Testing addition of time..");

        //get time 1
        System.out.print("Enter time1 (hhmm): ");
        input= scanner.nextLine();
        int  hh1=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));   
        int  mm1=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));

        //get time 2
        System.out.print("Enter time2 (hhmm): ");
        input= scanner.nextLine();
        int  hh2=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));   
        int  mm2=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));
        //add and display
        System.out.printf("Addition: %04d\n",time.addTime(hh1, mm1, hh2, mm2));


        //Testing subtraction
        System.out.println("Testing Subtraction of time..");
        System.out.print("Enter time1 (hhmm): ");
        input= scanner.nextLine();
        hh1=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));    
        mm1=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));

        System.out.print("Enter time2 (hhmm): ");
        input= scanner.nextLine();
        hh2=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));    
        mm2=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));
        System.out.printf("Subraction: %04d\n",time.addTime(hh1, mm1, hh2, mm2));

        //Testing copy
        System.out.println("Testing copy..");
        System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
        String inputFile= scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter output file:");
        String outputFile=scanner.nextLine();
        new NewCopyFile().copyFile(inputFile, outputFile);
        System.out.println("File copied");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is **not** a JUnit test. You should read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) page of JUnit.

Comment: I know, but I want to edit it for a JUnit test.

Comment: @Manu I dont understand how it works, I just cant get to grips with it. I made this code and I want to change it to accept JUnit but I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: I would take @Tunaki's advice on reading the get started page, and attempt to put this into a JUnit test class, and come back and ask the question with your new JUnit code. Not sure you need to provide as much code as you did, especially if the question is not clear. Attempt the JUnit test, think the question through and come back. I think that is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Not a unit test, as pointed out.  Your method takes four arguments?  So provide four.  You aren't going to interact with users or `System.out` in your JUnit test.

Your class is quite wrong.  This JUnit test proves that you've got a problem:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * NewTimeTest description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453866/how-to-change-my-code-into-taking-2-parameters-instead-of-4-for-junit-testing
 * @since 9/8/2015 5:34 AM
 */
public class NewTimeTest {

    @Test
    public void testValid24Time_Success() {
        NewTime newTime = new NewTime();
        for (int h = 0; h < 24; ++h) {
            for (int m = 0; m < 60; ++m) {
                Assert.assertTrue(String.format("Invalid time for %d:%d", h, m), newTime.valid24Time(h, m));
            }

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddTime() {
        NewTime newTime = new NewTime();
        int expected = 80;
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, newTime.addTime(0, 0, 1, 20));
    }
}
```

Comment: Only because you expect 80, doesn't mean his code is wrong. There is no specification saying the result is in minutes. The code is just weird :-)

Comment: Are you saying that adding an hour and 20 minutes to midnight should result in something else?  Weird, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you simply don't know how to write a JUnit test for your code. I'll give an example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        NewTime time = new NewTime();
        assertEquals(true, time.valid24Time(5, 30));
        assertEquals(false, time.valid24Time(5, 61));
        assertEquals(202, time.addTime(1, 1, 1, 1));
        assertEquals(1220, time.addTime(5, 5, 7, 15));
        assertEquals(0, time.subtractTime(1, 1, 1, 1));
        assertEquals(620, time.subtractTime(6, 10, 12, 30));
    }
}
```

By the way, your code is hard to read and use. Why does the last line result in 620, for example?

Comment: Yours isn't a good unit test, either.  I don't like cramming several methods into a single test.  One to a customer, please.  Better yet, have success and failure examples for each to show how they work.

Comment: I agree. I would write it differently at work, but this is just an example for a beginner :-)

Comment: Fair enough.   I'd still say that a proper example is not much more effort.